# Inheritance in Reporting Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, inheritance, reporting-services

Is there any way you can implement inheritance in Reporting Services?  I would like to have a master report, that contains the standard header and footer + some info in the beginning of the report, as well as containing some report parameters.  Then I would like to create a new report that inherits the master reports design and then I could add spesific content to that report.  Then if I needed to change a header logo or something, I could just alter the master report and that change would propagate to all inherited reports.  I'm looking for similar functionality as the asp.net masterpage gives on websites.

Is this at all possible using Reporting Services 2005, Visual Studio 2008 and c# ?  Or is there any workarounds that could help me achieve this?

I render all reports to pdf by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - but could not solve it in the given time so I put all the header, footer and sidebar information I needed on every report in subreports and integrated the subreports on all needed reports.

it's a very quick and dirty - copy-paste solution but it works now.

Comment: Yes, I also suspected that such a solution was all that was available now.  But can a subreport contain a page header, and is that header displayed on the final render ?

Comment: As far as I know - yes it can contain a header and a footer (since a subreport is a normal report) but I have no idea WHERE this things will be displayed. 
My advice - just try it out ;)

Comment: It's tried now, and it doesn't work I'm afraid.  I also found a web link that stated that only the body from a subreport will be rendered, but I can't see to find that now.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to achieve this using sub reports

Comment: I have now confirmed that only the body in subreports is rendered, so that only gives me a small part of the solution unfortunately.